# How to determine if multiple python binaries point to same installation

Tags: python, bash, python-3.x, macos

I've created a virtualenv for working on django, and for some reason, it holds three different binaries of python, which are python, python3 and python3.6. When I run `--version` for each of these, I get:

```
(django) usrname $ python --version
Python 3.6.2
(django) usrname $ python3 --version
Python 3.6.2
(django) usrname $ python3.6 --version
Python 3.6.2
```

Question 1:

Does these three binaries mean I have three different python versions installed in this virtualenv?

Question 2:

How do I go about removing the redundant installations/binaries?

EDIT: Here's what `ls -l` returned for each installation.

```
(django) Sahands-MacBook-Pro:django sahandzarrinkoub$ ls -l /Users/sahandzarrinkoub/.local/share/virtualenvs/django/bin/python3.6
-rwxr-xr-x  1 sahandzarrinkoub  staff  13068 Sep  8 11:25 /Users/sahandzarrinkoub/.local/share/virtualenvs/django/bin/python3.6
(django) Sahands-MacBook-Pro:django sahandzarrinkoub$ ls -l /Users/sahandzarrinkoub/.local/share/virtualenvs/django/bin/python3
lrwxr-xr-x  1 sahandzarrinkoub  staff  9 Sep  8 11:25 /Users/sahandzarrinkoub/.local/share/virtualenvs/django/bin/python3 -> python3.6
(django) Sahands-MacBook-Pro:django sahandzarrinkoub$ ls -l /Users/sahandzarrinkoub/.local/share/virtualenvs/django/bin/python
lrwxr-xr-x  1 sahandzarrinkoub  staff  9 Sep  8 11:25 /Users/sahandzarrinkoub/.local/share/virtualenvs/django/bin/python -> python3.6
```

Comment: You just have one python interpreter installed, it has 3 links for accessing it

Comment: How can one know that?

Comment: cd to the bin directory of the virtual environment and run ls -l. You will see that python and python3 are simply symbolic links to python3.6. Hence, there is only one python installation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run the `'ls -l'` command on the '`/usr/bin/python'` directory and it will display whether or not they are symbolic links

```
ekavala@elx75030xhv:~$ ll /usr/bin/python*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       9 Dec 21  2013 /usr/bin/python -> python2.7*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       9 Dec 21  2013 /usr/bin/python2 -> python2.7*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 3341384 Oct 26  2016 /usr/bin/python2.7*
```

Here we can see both links actually point to the `python2.7*` interpreter

```
ekavala@elx75030xhv:~$ python --version
Python 2.7.6
ekavala@elx75030xhv:~$ python2 --version
Python 2.7.6
ekavala@elx75030xhv:~$ python2.7 --version
Python 2.7.6
```

Comment: You can use 'ls -l' instead of ll

Comment: `ll` isn't a command; it's a commonly defined (but by no means universal) alias for `ls -l`.

Answer (score 1):

At first glance I would say that your virtual environment is not active. If it were, then the name of the virtual environment would be in parenthesis before the $ prompt. For example, if I create a virtualenv named testenv and activate it, my prompt would look something like this:

```
(testenv)  lenovo:davidj>
```

Without it activated it would look like this:

```
lenovo:davidj>
```

Make sure you activate the virtual environment.

Comment: Edited answer to clarify that it is activated.